# Best way to store and execute queries

Tags: airflow, scheduling

I started to migrate some pipelines to airflow and I am exploring the best practices. At my case I have a pipelines/dags that executes several sql scripts (mostly sequentially). I am thinking of:

- having one dynamic task to execute these queries
- save all queries in a folder per dag
- store the order of the queries in another file (probably yaml)

I know that this is going to work but are there any better approaches?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow certainly supports the use of templated scripts and specifically a very broadly tooled way of applying SQL over the DbAPiHook. Basically, most ways you can think of storing, loading, and presenting your SQL files to your architecture Airflow will support.

There are a couple of concepts you might want to look into:

- [SQLOperators](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/mysql/operators/mysql.py) the main interface for [DbAPIHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py)
- [template suffix](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L286)
- [template search path](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L142:L145) on the DAG model... will be where Airflow looks for a file you include in your templates arg.
- [operater.render_template](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L873) which uses Jinja to push variables from your runtime context into the template.

As such you could have something like:

```py
Task = SQLOperator(
  dag=dag,
  task_id="sql_task",
  sql=["filename1.sql", "filename2.sql"]
)
```

That should give you all you need to implement exactly as you like.